# Adding stage to PUBLISHED when created a comment on GRAPHQL

Tags: graphql, next.js, graphql-js

i have a little blog site created with Nextjs, GraphQL and GraphCMS, and already the create comment functionality works, but i have to stage manually to PUBLISHED on the CMS. I want to the comment already staging to PUBLISHED when created.

There is the mutation code.

```js
   const query = gql`
   mutation CreateComment($name: String!, $email: String!, $comment: String!, $slug: String!) {
     createComment(data: {name : $name, email : $email, comment: $comment, post: { connect: { slug: $slug}}}) { id }
   }
 `
```

That's all my code

```js
    import { GraphQLClient, gql } from 'graphql-request';

    const graphqlAPI = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHCMS_ENDPOINT
    const graphcmsToken = process.env.GRAPHCMS_TOKEN

    export default async function comments(req, res) {
  
    const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(graphqlAPI, {
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${graphcmsToken}`
    }
    })

    const query = gql`
    mutation CreateComment($name: String!, $email: String!, $comment: 
    String!, $slug: String!) {
      createComment(data: {name : $name, email : $email, comment: 
    $comment, post: { connect: { slug: $slug}}}) { id }
    }
    `
 
      try {
      const result = await graphQLClient.request(query, req.body);

       return res.status(200).send(result);
       } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
      return res.status(500).send(error);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**

Okay after a bit of research , I found that every **model** in **GraphCMS** have some pre-defined resolver functions. So to directly **PUBLISH** your content you need to update your mutation function like this:

```js
  const query = gql`
    mutation CreateComment($name: String!, $email: String!, $comment: 
    String!, $slug: String!) {
      createComment(data: {name : $name, email : $email, comment: 
    $comment, post: { connect: { slug: $slug}}}) { id }
    
    publishComment(where : {slug:$slug}) {
            title
        }
    }

    `
```

You will have to   replace the `slug` field in `publishComment` resolver  with your unique field in case `slug` isn't your unique field.

[Publishing Content](https://graphcms.com/docs/api-reference/content-api/content-stages#publishing-content)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i already tried that but it doesn't work, i post all my code, maybe is some issue here.

Comment: I have edited my answer, see if it works.

Comment: It works like charm, thanks so much

Comment: If you found my answer useful , please upvote it and accept it as your answer. It will help.